# How to set a nil pointer of a struct to the zero value of struct using reflection in Go?

Tags: go, reflection, struct

I am crawling a struct recursively. It's identical to what the `json` package does. If a nil pointer to a struct is encountered, the pointer should be set to the zero value of the struct to be able to continue digging. How can I achieve this?

```
var unmarshal func(s reflect.Value) error
unmarshal = func(s reflect.Value) error {
    t := s.Type()
    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        v := s.Field(i)
        f := t.Field(i)
        kind := v.Kind()
        if key, ok := f.Tag.Lookup("env"); ok {
            // ...
        } else if kind == reflect.Struct {
            unmarshal(v)
        } else if kind == reflect.Ptr && v.Elem().Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            if v.IsNil() {
                // Set pointer to zero value of struct.
            }
            unmarshal(v.Elem())
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for the down-vote?

Comment: Is the pointer a struct field? If not, where does the struct field come in? Please show more context in your code so we can understand what you're doing. It would also be good to know the actual problem you're trying to solve, this feels like like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I see, the terminology was messed up.

Comment: You are assigning to a function result. Why? Maybe you mean `refelct.Zero(f.Type). Interface()`

Comment: It also seem like an XY problem, so it would be good if you can provide what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't think it benefits the question but if it's required to explain.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If `v` is not nil, you can use `v.Elem().Set(reflect.New(v.Type().Elem()))`. But if `v` is nil, I don't know how to get around it.

Comment: Provide input and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reflect.New(f.Type.Elem())` to create a pointer to the zero value and then `v.Set(value)` to set it.  As per the reflect docs:

`New returns a Value representing a pointer to a new zero value for the specified type. That is, the returned Value's Type is PtrTo(typ).`

Full example in Go Playground here:

https://play.golang.org/p/b-034h3I-cn

Note that I also did `f.Type.Elem().Kind()` in the if statement rather `v.Elem().Kind()` that you have as that is asking for the `Kind()` of `nil` which is invalid.